# I have a data as per tally now i want a data as per my Database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

i want to pivot data in sql,
i have data and i attached script so you can create same in your structure

```
CREATE TABLE pivot1
(
date DATE,
ledger VARCHAR(100),
ReceiptType NVARCHAR(50),
Debit DECIMAL(18, 4),
credit DECIMAL(18, 4)
);

INSERT INTO pivot1 VALUES('01-01-2018','G-704 Rushang Vora','receipt',200,NULL)
INSERT INTO pivot1 VALUES(NULL,'icici 0000123456789',NULL,NULL,100)
INSERT INTO pivot1 VALUES(NULL,'abc',NULL,NULL,NULL)

INSERT INTO pivot1 VALUES('01-01-2018','G-705 Shailesh Sevra','receipt',NULL,'500')
INTO pivot1 VALUES(NULL,'Kotak 00012456',NULL,'200',NULL)
INSERT INTO pivot1 VALUES(NULL,'pqr',NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

now my data table is like

```
date        ledger                  ReceiptType Debit       credit      
2018-01-01  G-704 Rushang Vora      Receipt     200.0000    NULL        
NULL        ICICI 0000123456789     NULL        NULL        100.0000    
NULL        abc                     NULL        NULL        NULL        
2018-01-01  G-705 Shailesh Sevra    receipt     NULL        500.0000    
NULL        Kotak 00012456          NULL        200.0000    NULL        
NULL        pqr                     NULL        NULL        NULL
```

i want my sql query which is giving me result as like below:

```
date        ledger                bankdetails          comments receipttype debit credit 
2018-01-01  G-704 Rushang Vora    ICICI 0000123456789  abc      receipt     200   100
2018-01-01  G-705 Shailesh Sevra  Kotak 00012456       pqr      receipt     200   500
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your transformation seems to require knowledge of the ordering of rows, which requires an explicit column. How is this ordering determined?  What is the relationship among the rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic is a little unclear, but you seem to have groups of 3 adjacent rows which are summarized.  Unfortunately, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no such thing as "3 adjacent rows".

However, if I add an identity column to the data, then the table will capture the insertion order.  This allows us to define the groups and aggregate using a query such as:

```
select grp, max(date) as date,
       max(case when seqnum = 0 then ledger end) as ledger,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then ledger end) as bankdetails,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then ledger end) as comment,
       max(receipttype) as receipttype,
       sum(debit) as debit,
       sum(credit) as credit
from (select  p.*,
              (row_number() over (order by id) - 1) % 3 as seqnum,
              (row_number() over (order by id) - 1) / 3 as grp
      from pivot1 p
     ) p
group by grp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8fe6e0428d32377299981bcc84b3ed97) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: hey its really helpful for me, but i want to suggetion from your side can i get the same result without use "id" column?

Comment: @shael . . . You need a column that specifies the ordering of the rows or identifies which rows should go together in the final result.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a little modification on your code to be able to achieve the result expected. I had to create an INT column to be able to group the sets. If you have a column that is able to do that, just replace it. If you don't have a column like that, let me know and I think I can make it work without this workaround. I also got curious about your question so let me know of other solutions for the same problem.

```
CREATE TABLE #pivot1
(
[IDENTITYCOL] INT,
date DATE,
ledger VARCHAR(100),
ReceiptType NVARCHAR(50),
Debit DECIMAL(18, 4),
credit DECIMAL(18, 4)
);

INSERT INTO #pivot1 VALUES(1,'01-01-2018','G-704 Rushang Vora','receipt',200,NULL)
INSERT INTO #pivot1 VALUES(1,NULL,'icici 0000123456789',NULL,NULL,100)
INSERT INTO #pivot1 VALUES(1,NULL,'abc',NULL,NULL,NULL)

INSERT INTO #pivot1 VALUES(2,'01-01-2018','G-705 Shailesh Sevra','receipt',NULL,'500')
INSERT INTO #pivot1 VALUES(2,NULL,'Kotak 00012456',NULL,'200',NULL)
INSERT INTO #pivot1 VALUES(2,NULL,'pqr',NULL,NULL,NULL)


WITH PIVOTCTE AS
(
    SELECT [IDENTITYCOL],DATE 
    ,CASE 
        WHEN LEDGER LIKE 'G-%' THEN LEDGER
    END AS LEDGER
    ,CASE 
        WHEN LEDGER LIKE '%[a-z]%' AND LEDGER LIKE '%[0-9]%'AND LEDGER NOT LIKE '%-%' THEN LEDGER
    END AS BANKDETAILS
    ,CASE 
        WHEN LEDGER LIKE '%[a-z]%' AND LEDGER NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%' THEN LEDGER
    END AS COMMENTS
    , RECEIPTTYPE ,DEBIT, CREDIT 
    FROM #pivot1 
)
SELECT MAX(DATE) AS DATE 
,MAX(LEDGER) AS LEDGER
,MAX(BANKDETAILS) AS BANKDETAILS
,MAX(COMMENTS) AS COMMENTS
,MAX(RECEIPTTYPE) AS RECEIPTTYPE
,MAX(DEBIT) AS DEBIT
,MAX(CREDIT) AS CREDIT
FROM PIVOTCTE
GROUP BY [IDENTITYCOL]
```